# Emulating Python's `index(separator, start_index)` in Rust

Tags: unicode, rust

I'm currently porting a library from Python from Rust and found a line for which I'm having trouble finding the right "translation":

```
right = s.index(sep, left)
```

where `right` is the index of the first instance of `sep` found in string `s` that is after index `left`.

A simple example of this can be seen here:

> Python 3

```
>>> s = "Hello, my name is erip and my favorite color is green."
>>> right = s.index("my", 10) # Find index of first instance of 'my' after index 10
>>> print right
27
>>> print s[27:]
my favorite color is green.
```

My attempt in Rust is:

```
// s: &str, sep: &str, left: usize
let right = s[left..].find(sep).unwrap() + left;
```

This will search the bytes after `left` for `sep`. This [seems to work](http://is.gd/RPEmu1) when using ASCII characters. There seems to be a problem when using Unicode, though:

> Python 3

```
>>> s = "Hello, mÿ name is erip and mÿ favorite color is green."
>>> right = s.index("mÿ", 10)
>>> print(right)
27
```

> [Rust](http://is.gd/s66Tq4)

```
fn main() {
    let sep: &str = "mÿ";
    let left: usize = 10;
    let s: &str = "Hello, mÿ name is erip and mÿ favorite color is green.";
    let right = s[left..].find(sep).unwrap() + left;
    println!("{}", right); //prints 28
}
```

I realize that Python 2 would also give 28 because it doesn't support Unicode natively, but I'd like to mimic Python 3's results.

The problem is because `usize` in Rust refers to the number of *bytes* in a string because "mÿ" actually requires 3 bytes to encode. How can I acquire this desired behavior in Rust?

I'm using `rustc 1.4.0`.

Comment: *because `usize` [...] refers to the number of bytes in a string* — that's true in this case, but isn't true universally. A `usize` is a machine-sized unsigned integer, good for when counting amounts of things bounded by the machine's memory.

Comment: Stylistically, there's no reason to have any of the type declarations that you have in your `main`. All of them can be inferred.

Comment: I suspect an X/Y problem: the index is probably used by something else afterward, so the unit (and thus value) of the index itself does not matter (whether in graphemes, codepoints or bytes) as long as the unit is shared by the consumer => Do you really want to have an index in codepoints? Or graphemes? Or would bytes work, as long as the consumer can be adapted to work with bytes too?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm using this in a tokenizer - I want the index in graphemes. i.e., I shouldn't need to worry about the number of **bytes** in the string. Rather the position of the character irrespective of the encoding scheme.

Comment: Yeah, I think @MatthieuM. nailed it on the head. Especially for tokenizers - if they produce consistent slices around UTF-8 bytes, then that's all you need. That's how every other Rust lexer / tokenizer / parser that I've looked at works.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Depends, sometimes you might want the index in graphemes; for example, when underlining a portion of the text with "~~~" on the next line, you need to reason not in terms of bytes or code points in the terminal, but in terms of graphemes (supposing a monospace font, common in terminals). For the tokenizer I would not be surprised that both byte and grapheme indexing be needed at once.

Answer (score 3):

Let's restate the problem a bit as it's unclear what the unit of `index` should be. Humans believe that strings are easy because we've been using them for most of our lives. However, things aren't nearly as easy as we'd like.

Rust takes the point-of-view that strings (`&str` or `String`) are UTF-8 encoded sequences of bytes. Jumping into a string using a byte offset is O(1), and you really want that level of performance guarantee to build more complicated things upon.

I don't know what Python considers that index to be. It gets *hard* once you get beyond simple encoding schemes like ASCII where one character is one byte. There are multiple ways to chunk a Unicode string depending on what you want. Two obvious ones are by Unicode codepoint and by grapheme.

Since codepoints can be represented in Rust using a `char`, that's what I assume you want. However, you are the only one that can figure that out.

Additionally, since you requested that the result be `28`, that must be the number of bytes into the string. It's a little odd to skip N codepoints but return bytes, but it is what it is.

---

<s>Now that we know what we are doing</s>... let's try and do it. (See next solution where I read the desired outcome better).

The key thing you need to use is [`char_indices`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices). This is an O(n) operation that walks through the string and and gives you each codepoint and its corresponding byte offset.

Then, it's just a matter of putting that together and correctly handling cases of walking off the end of the string. This is made obvious by Rust's strong types, hooray!

```
// `index` is the number of Unicode codepoints to skip
// The result is the number of **bytes** inside the haystack
// that the needle can be found.
fn python_index(haystack: &str, needle: &str, index: usize) -> Option<usize> {
    haystack.char_indices().nth(index).and_then(|(byte_idx, _)| {
        let leftover = &haystack[byte_idx..];
        leftover.find(needle).map(|inner_idx| inner_idx + byte_idx)
    })
}

fn main() {
    let right = python_index("Hello, mÿ name is erip and mÿ favorite color is green.", "mÿ", 10);
    println!("{:?}", right); // prints Some(28)
}
```

---

We do the same high-level concept as above, but once we have found the `needle`, we then reset back and iterate through the codepoints again. When we find the same byte offset of the substring, we terminate.

Then it's just a matter of counting the characters we saw and adding the number that we already skipped.

```
// `index` is the number of Unicode codepoints to skip
// The result is the number of codepoints inside the haystack
// that the needle can be found.
fn python_index(haystack: &str, needle: &str, index: usize) -> Option<usize> {
    haystack.char_indices().nth(index).and_then(|(byte_idx, _)| {
        let leftover = &haystack[byte_idx..];

        leftover.find(needle).map(|inner_offset| {
            leftover.char_indices().take_while(|&(inner_inner_offset, _)| {
                inner_inner_offset != inner_offset
            }).count() + index
        })
    })
}

fn main() {
    let right = python_index("Hello, mÿ name is erip and mÿ favorite color is green.", "mÿ", 10);
    println!("{:?}", right); // prints Some(27)
}
```

This certainly feels not super-efficient; you'd want to benchmark to see how it fares. However, the `find` implementation is pretty optimized, so I'd rather use it and then do a straight-shot through the characters and trust in the cache and prefetching to help me out ^_^.

Comment: I actually wanted the result to be `27`. My result was already printing `28`.

Comment: I want to find the index of the first instance of `sep` found in string `s` that is after index `left`. I want to find the index character-wise, not byte-wise. I think `char_indices` is still what I want.

Comment: @erip updated. I don't really understand the purpose of this, as it will break as soon as you start including combining characters...

Comment: That's kind of the point of the question. I want a way that is efficient and not a kludge.

Comment: @erip you never once mentioned "performance" or "efficiency" in your question; you simply asked for an equivalent functionality. Perhaps you should ask another question, as [modifying a question dramatically is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179215/edited-question-makes-answers-incorrect). Or you can downvote this and wait for someone else to provide a more desired answer.